# When printing Arrays in C some numbers print as 0.00

Tags: c, arrays, printing

This code asks for 10 simple values to create an array and then prints them. The `scanf` is correct, you can enter the 10 values normally.

The problem is, when printing, that every single value from 1 to 10 is printed as expected but the 7 & 8 values are printed as 0.00. I thought it could be that the for loop is not running correctly but the other numbers are printed just fine.

Does anyone know whats the problem? Why just 7 & 8? Can I fix it using the same structure?
Appreciate the help, I'm new to this. This is what I have:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int index;
    int size = 10;
    float values[index];
    for (index=0; index < size; index++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value[%1d]: ",index+1);
        scanf("%f",&values[index]);
    }
    for(index=0; index < size; index++)
    {
        printf("\nvalue[%1d]= ", index+1);
        printf("%.2f", values[index]);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `index` is uninitialized when defining `values`: `float values[index];`. Did you mean to use size instead `float values[size];`?

Comment: You initialize values array with index instead of size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple mix up...
When you create `float values[index];` `index` is uninitialized, which results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change this:

```
int index;
int size = 10;
float values[index];
               ^
```

To this:

```
int index;
int size = 10;
float values[size];
              ^
```